# Demonstrating that $\int_0^L \frac{1}{r(\ell)} d\ell = \ln \frac{R_1 + R_2 + L}{R_1 + R_2 - L}$ where $R_1 = r(0)$ and $R_2 = r(L)$

Tags: calculus

I am to integrate $1/r$ along a straight line of length $L$, where $r$ is the distance to a fixed point (not on the line). I've come across the following result in a thesis without proof:

$$
\int_0^L \frac{1}{r(\ell)} d\ell = \ln \frac{R_1 + R_2 + L}{R_1 + R_2 - L}
$$

Where

$$
R_1 = r(0)\\
R_2 = r(L)
$$

The following image illustrates the values

[image: ilus]

I did some numerical testings and the result seems to be correct, but I could not prove it.

---

What I tried so far is (the actual problem is 3-dimensional, but it should not make a difference because of symmetry):

Assume the fixed point is on $(x_p, y_p)$, the line starts at $(0,0)$ and ends at $(L,0)$. Then

$$
\int_0^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x_p - x)^2 + y_p^2}} dx = \ln \left ( \frac{\left (x_p + \sqrt{x_p^2 + y_p^2} \right ) \left (L - x_p + \sqrt{(L - x_p)^2 + y_p^2} \right )}{\left (-x_p + \sqrt{x_p^2 + y_p^2} \right ) \left (L - x_p - \sqrt{(L - x_p)^2 + y_p^2} \right )}\right )
$$

$$
\int_0^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x_p - x)^2 + y_p^2}} dx = \ln \left ( \frac{(x_p + R_1) (L - x_p + R_2)}{(-x_p + R_1) (L - x_p - R_2)} \right )
$$

and I can't simplify further to remove $x_p$ from the expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very good at the whole image/visualization on MSE - but if you imagine you draw a perpendicular line from the apex (point where all lines intersect) of your triangle and label the height of that line as $h$ the point at which this line hits the base is $x$ we can write a couple of equations as
$$
R_2^2 = h^2 + x^2\\
R_1^2 = h^2 + (L-x)^2\\
r(l)^2 = h^2 + (l - x)^2
$$
we can see that we obtain the top equations by letting the bottom be $0, L$. This height, $h$, is the constant quantity between all lines, so makes sense to use this.

we know have an equation similar to yours
$$
\int_0^L\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2+(l-x)^2}} dl = \left[\ln\left(\sqrt{h^2 + (l-x)^2} + l -x\right)\right]_0^L
$$
we then have
$$
\ln\left(\sqrt{h^2 + (L-x)^2} + L -x\right) - \ln\left(\sqrt{h^2 + (0-x)^2} + 0 -x\right) = \ln\left(\sqrt{h^2 + (L-x)^2} + L -x\right) - \ln\left(\sqrt{h^2 + x^2}  -x\right) 
$$
This becomes
$$
\ln\left(R_1 + L -x\right) - \ln\left(R_2  -x\right)  = \ln\left(\frac{R_1 + L -x}{R_2  -x}\right)
$$
now lets find $x$
we have
$$
R_2^2 - h^2 = x^2\\
R_1^2 - h^2 = L^2 - 2Lx + x^2
$$
this becomes
$$
R_2^2 - R_1^2 = 2Lx - L^2 \implies \frac{R_2^2-R_1^2+L^2}{2L} = x
$$
inserting into solution for $2xL$ 
$$
\frac{R_1 + L -x}{R_2  -x} = \frac{2R_1L + 2L^2 - 2xL}{2R_2L  -2xL} = \frac{2R_1L + 2L^2 - (R_2^2 - R_1^2  + L^2)}{2R_2L - (R_2^2 - R_1^2  + L^2)} = \frac{(L+R_1)^2-R_2^2}{R_1^2-(L-R_2)^2}
$$
This becomes
$$
\frac{(L+R_1)^2-R_2^2}{R_1^2-(L-R_2)^2} = \frac{(L+R_1 -R_2)(L+R_1 + R_2)}{(R_1 +R_2 - L)(R_1 - R_2 + L)} = \frac{(L+R_1 + R_2)}{(R_1 +R_2 - L)}
$$
or finally
$$
\int_0^L \frac{1}{r(l)}dl = \ln\left(\frac{R_1 + L -x}{R_2  -x}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{R_1 + R_2 + L}{R_1 +R_2 - L}\right)
$$